# Do I need a new roof to install ridge vents?

Tags: roof, ventilation, contractors

I wanted to have a ridge vent installed across the top of my roof to improve ventilation.

Roof is about 40ft long with a ridge board in the middle and 5/12 pitch.

Roofer came out saying he can't install it unless he puts in a new roof too.

When asked why, he said that I have shiplap and need to have it replaced with plywood.

*Does ridge vent actually require plywood under the shingles?*

I feel like he's just trying to up-sell for a full replacement, but I don't know anything about roofs so maybe it's true. Hoping someone can shed some light or point me to some nice resources to read.

Comment: Talk to another roofer, or do it yourself. If your roof deck is in good condition this is pure upsell or FUD (Fear, Uncertainty & Doubt.) Boards are not a problem if they are not rotting.

Comment: Roofs were decked with boards back when slate was used, and lasted 100+ years. Perhaps he doubts his ability to rip (cut) the topmost board to open a slot for the vent.

Comment: @crip659, shiplap was a common roof decking choice 60 years ago. There are still plenty around.

Comment: Are you sure it's "ship lap" not "skip lap", "skip lath", or "skip sheathing"? Our roof was skip sheathed as the original layer was cedar shakes. Two additional layers of asphalt shingles had been put over the shakes, then when we redid the roof, all of that came off and the skip sheathing was covered with plywood to support the new asphalt shingles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ridge vent requires a channel to be cut down the ridge. With plywood or OSB this usually isn't a problem. With shiplap it may result in very narrow strips being left behind, which could leave the ridge poorly supported.

Another possibility is that some of the wood near the ridge is degraded by rot or just age. This could also leave some instability and would need repair (made slightly more challenging by the presence of roofing).

That said, I don't see how it would be prohibitive. Worst case scenario I'd float some backing under the remaining strips and screw it in place. Nothing to it. Sounds like your roofer has more work than needed and is being choosy.

If you're comfortable on the roof, this is a fairly easy DIY project. Feel free to ask about that in another post if you like.